# Linking GMP into a baremetal program

Tags: linker, gmp, bare-metal

I have some code which relies on a library, namely the University of Tsukuba Elliptic Pairing Library. This library itself relies on GMP. I'd like to run this program baremetal on an ARM core, specifically on a beaglebone black.

GMP is a massive library, so I'd prefer to cross-compile if possible. I'd also prefer something other than the ``brute force" solution of simply dumping the entire GMP source code into the same file as my program and pushing it into arm-none-eabi-gcc.

What is the standard method for linking nontrivial libraries into baremetal code?

Comment: Did you look at mini-gmp (inside the gmp sources)?

Comment: @MarcGlisse, I discovered that an hour or so after posting this question. It seems to be able to do what I need it to, but is creating some errors in my toolchain. It's nearly midnight where I live right now, but I'll poke it some more in the morning and, if this turns out to be a good solution, I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

In this specific case, mini-gmp is sufficient, providing a bunch of functionality is removed from TEPLA. This is sufficient for my purposes, but hardly a satisfying answer -- my solution to linking a nontrivial library is to instead link a trivial library. Though my exact problem is solved, I'll be leaving this question open in case someone has any cleverer ideas.