# Using GMP in freestanding programs

Tags: c++, c, performance, linker, shared-libraries

Is it possible to use GMP in a freestanding environment?

I am working on a program that must run on bare metal (to reduce overhead and also for security purposes - outside code isn't allowed), forcing me to create a minimalistic kernel, however, I also need to use GMP for arbitrarily large integers. I have looked at mini-GMP, however it seems to be orders of magnitude slower than real (full) GMP.

Please note: I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22771688/linking-gmp-into-a-baremetal-program) question, however there seem to be no answers other than the one in which the OP said he was happy with mini-GMP..

Comment: What are the issues you encounter when you attempt to use/link against GMP?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth GMP works fine for normal programs, but when used in a program that is compiled with -ffreestanding the linker reports undefined reference errors whenever a GMP function is used.

Comment: A freestanding environment does not necessarily provide the C standard library.  If you want to use standard library functions in such an environment, or to use a third-party library that does so, then you need to be prepared to provide your own implementations of the needed functions.  That's certainly possible, but it may turn out to be a fairly large number of functions that need to be provided, and you need to take care that your implementations conform.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I have constructed a small stdlib.h/c for my kernel that has all of the basic functions (in which I have tried my best to conform to standard) and I understand that I should technically be writing my own arbitrary precision arithmetic library for such a project, however nothing I can write will be nearly as efficient as GMP or ARPREC

Comment: If the linker complains about undefined references then it is because you have not provided all the functions GMP relies upon.  By the way, are you building GMP for your freestanding environment, or are you trying to use one that was pre-built (for a hosted environment)?  If the latter, then do build your own GMP for the target environment -- it will help you ensure that all the dependencies are satisfied, and it may altogether avoid dependencies on certain internal functions (not) provided by the compiler's run-time library.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to link static libraries into a freestanding executable.  It's just like linking more object files.

So build a static version of GMP (ideally with `-march=atom` or whatever is appropriate for your target hardware).  Put `libgmp.a` somewhere and use `-Ldir` to tell the compiler where.

I haven't tried this myself for GMP, so I can't guarantee there are no complications in building a static GMP, but the build scripts for most packages include an option to build static libraries.  (e.g. `--enable-static`)